# Nginx forward /socket.io requests to proxied nodejs server

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, proxy, socket.io

I am trying to forward all `/socket.io` requests to `/broadcaster`. Here is my nginx config:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        access_log /home/ubuntu/logs/broadcaster/access.log;
        error_log /home/ubuntu/logs/broadcaster/error.log;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name localhost;

        # Enable WS
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_redirect off;

        location /broadcaster {
                rewrite  ^/broadcaster/(.*)  /$1 break;
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1337;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }
        # simply forward socket.io requests.
        # only one site can run socket.io on this server now
        location /socket.io {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1337;
        #       proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        #       proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        }

}
```

When I (socket.io) makes a request like `GET http://my-ec2-public-dns/socket.io/1/?t=1408981904508` I get the error `400 (Bad Request)`.
How can I nginx forward the `/socket.io` requests?

Comment: Hi! Have you resolved this issue? I'm experiencing very similar one and would appretiate any hints. Here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29043879/socket-io-with-nginx

Comment: I don't know what specifically was the fix, but I now have a domain name, and my nginx config is doing a proxy pass for the subdomain and it just works. Sorry I can't help.