# Sockets Connecting

Tags: javascript, socket.io, wamp, wampserver

I have been trying to get my WAMP Webserver run with socket.io but I just cannot seem to get it to work.

My socket server is on port 3000 and the WAMP on port 80. I know that both servers work.

Web Server Client Code:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io('http://[ip address]:3000');
    socket.on('buzz', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
});
</script>
```

Console Error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined
at (index):97
```

**UPDATE**
I was missing the socket.io.js file. But now I am getting

```
GET http://[[IP]]:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LxfQwpE
net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

In the console every few seconds.

Comment: Does your web developer console in your web browser tell you anything? Suggests socket.io.js has not been included when you try and instantiate the `io` object.

Comment: Oops looks like I was missing the socket.io.js folder

Comment: Cool. Easy fix. Can also use CDN with ease for client includes. `<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-2.?.?.js"></script>`... just plugin correct version numbers.

Comment: @ficuscr Thanks! That worked but I am now getting the above (edited OP) error msg.

Comment: What happens when you ping your server? I know you said "both servers work", but your socket server might not be receiving the request.

Comment: When I go to localhost:3000, the server responds with index.html (node server)

Comment: Show us your server code for socket.io.

Comment: Here: https://gist.github.com/Nepaltechguy2/9bec5afc5ce7964661219abd75efb140

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I recall, this problem was solved by installing a NGINX reverse proxy -- I believe I followed the instructions here: [Socket.io with nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29043879/socket-io-with-nginx)

This was one of my first projects, but I thought I would point people in the right direction in case other students wish to use a WAMP backend and Socket.io.