# WebSocket connection to 'wss://' Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

Tags: node.js, sockets, nginx, websocket, socket.io

I use `socket.io` in my `node.js` app that's running on `express`.

Everything words fine on the local version (`localhost`) however when I switch to my production server (which is served via `https` using a custom certificate), I get the following error in my browser console:

`websocket.js:112 WebSocket connection to 'wss://infranodus.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=j_WBxkPY_RlpF9_ZAANP' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400`

I made a research ([issue referenced here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1942)) and it turns out this happens because my app / hosting provider blocks connections like `wss` and my `socket.io` falls back on `AJAX` to make requests (which functions OK, but sometimes there are bugs).

So I wanted to ask you if I could do modifications to my app to get rid of this error?

Just FYI currently all requests to http://infranodus.com are forwarded (via static .htaccess) to https://infranodus.com and my `app.js` file (the part of the server activation looks like that):

```
var http = require('http');

var app = express();

var server = http.Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

and the way I require sockets in my front-end file:

`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

and then

`var socket = io();`

Maybe the problem is that I activate server in my node.js app using `http` and not `https`? But I would not like to switch to that because I don't know where my certificates are stored and I would not like to change the backend code too much.

**UPDATE (21/10/2018):** We figured out the problem is [with nginx server](https://github.com/nicokaiser/nginx-websocket-proxy/blob/master/simple-wss.conf) and due to the limitations of some hosting providers who do not allow users to edit nginx servers, websockets over secure protocol get blocked or get 400 error. It would be nice to resolve this in sockets.io as it's a problem that many users have. Any ideas?

**TO REPRODUCE THE ISSUE:** Please, go open your Javascript Console and go to https://infranodus.com/news/english

**SOURCE CODE:** https://github.com/noduslabs/infranodus

Comment: Where are you hosting your app?, Do you have multiple servers, or just one?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande I only have one server and I'm hosting it on Webfaction

Comment: Do you have an nginx server in front of your node app?

Comment: I think so, @MarcosCasagrande - how do I check?

Comment: If you are not sure, probably don't have control over it, and you won't be able to change anything. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29043879/socket-io-with-nginx

Comment: Ok, so I need to find another solution...

Comment: Which provider do you use for hosting? Have you confirmed with them that they do block websockets? When you say I use a custom certificate, does it mean a self-signed certificate or an actual certificate your purchases from a recognized provider?

Comment: @TarunLalwani i use ComodoSSL certificate. The hosting provider is WebFaction and say they have everything opened.

Comment: Can you post your `.htaccess`? and I assume the Certificate is automatically configure at WebFaction?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I don't have any .htaccess — all the code I have in my root is available on https://github.com/noduslabs/infranodus

Comment: @TarunLalwani and yes, the certificate is added through WebFaction control panel.

Comment: Have you checked if firewall settings particular to your server allows connection through the web socket port?

Answer (score 6):

I solved it with this:

```
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:3000", {
   forceNew: true,
   transports: ["polling"],
});
```

Comment: Thank you, mate. I solved the issue with this solution.

Comment: Yep, this worked like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Check if you using `express-status-monitor` as a middleware on express, this makes http call on the first (request) handshake of WebSocket goes failed, if not maybe another factor like proxy (nginx) or similar like that

Look [here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1942) More details about this error

Comment: Oh yes, I was all over that page, but no help there. And yes, it's a nginx issue and if I had access to my nginx server I could sort this out but how to resolve it when I don't have access? I develop this code so people can also install it on other servers and not all servers have the capacity to go to that level of config, so what to do?

Comment: When I face this problem try to break down every middleware attached into express, then do checking if the handshake issue was resolved by dropping them one by one. At the first place you should check that your application is not the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use a secure URL for your initial connection, i.e. instead of "http://" use "https://". If the WebSocket transport is chosen, then Socket.IO should automatically use "wss://" (SSL) for the WebSocket connection too.

If you are not specifying any URL when you call io(), since it defaults trying to connect to the host that serves the page, either you have to provide url or change to https

```
  var socket = io.connect('https://localhost', {secure: true}); //remote url
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error.

I decided to visit [infranodus.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=j_WBxkPY_RlpF9_ZAANP](http://infranodus.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=j_WBxkPY_RlpF9_ZAANP) which returns the message "Session ID unknown".

Did you use multiple nodes ? If this is the case, please refer to the site https://socket.io/docs/using-multiple-nodes/.

As it says on the official site,

> If you plan to distribute the load of connections among different
>   processes or machines, you have to make sure that requests associated
>   with a particular session id connect to the process that originated
>   them.
>
> This is due to certain transports like XHR Polling or JSONP Polling
>   relying on firing several requests during the lifetime of the
>   “socket”. Failing to enable sticky balancing will result in the
>   dreaded:
>
> `Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400`

Reconfigure the Nginx config as explain then try to adapt the Express like this

```
let port = parseInt(your_port) + parseInt(process.env.NODE_APP_INSTANCE);
server.listen(port, console.log("Server running "+port));
```

Let us know if it changes something :)

Comment: Hey no I don't use multiple nodes. I think in my particular case the problem is the nginx server in between which i cannot configure because WebFaction hosting does not allow this... It would be nice to find a workaround though...

Comment: Thank you, it was my case, — I was needed to modify Nginx configuration, because Nginx was preventing connections to be established.

Answer (score 1):

Try this two method if this work for you

**Try this method 1:**

I was facing the same issue. After 30 min debug I resolved the issue by enabling ALB (Application Load Balancer) Stickiness. It worked for me.

**Try this method 2:**

```
// Client side adding transport param:
var socket = io('http://localhost:3000', { transports: ['websocket'] });
```

> You can set this value 'http://localhost:3000' as per your domain.

Comment: How to enable that?

Comment: Go to Load Balancer > Select Target Group > and down below there is a button to edit > Edit the button and enable the Stickiness.

Comment: You're probably on Amazon, but my server is on WebFaction. Also, I tried the settings you provided, but that didn't do anything...

Comment: Yes, I am using the Amazon and it is working fine. Try some troubleshoot

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem when I updated packages on the backend, python socketio, but didn't do it on the frontend.

But when I updated the packages everywhere, the problem was fixed.
This was a problem in versions

I found this error in the browser after navigating to the link when the 400 error returned
"The client is using an unsupported version of the Socket.IO or Engine.IO protocols"