# socket.io can't connect when clients are on different wifi (ip address)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, socket.io, multiplayer

socket.io can't connect when clients are on different wifi (ip address) on my self-configured ubuntu nginx server, but works perfectly fine on a pre-configured heroku server

this is my nginx config

```
upstream dirtyfinger {
    ip_hash;
    server localhost:3000;
    server localhost:3001;
    server localhost:3002;
    server localhost:3003;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_pass "http://dirtyfinger/";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:
   `proxy_pass "http://dirtyfinger/";`

To this:
    `proxy_pass http://dirtyfinger/;`

And potentially lose the end '/', though I am not 100% on that.

Docs:
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/

Comment: thanks but this doesn't solve the socket.io connection problem

Comment: Looking around some more there is another question regarding this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29043879/socket-io-with-nginx). How are you reaching the site via your ubuntu nginx server vs the heroku setup? Can you post some additional information?

Comment: the application code are completely the same, the only difference is i'm running my own configured nginx server vs don't know how heroku is running my app which works fine

Comment: Can you add the nginx logging and post the logs from both? https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/monitoring/logging/#setting-up-the-access-log