# Socket.io not working and constantly polling with nginx

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, mern

I have a MERN fullstack application that uses socket.io for live chat and works fine in dev, but it's not working in production. instead, it's constantly doing polling.

here is my current configuration:

services.js in front

```
export const API = axios.create({
    baseURL : 'https://myurl.com/api',
    withCredentials: true,
    timeout: 6000,
    headers : APIHeaders
});

export const socketURL = 'https://myurl.com/api'
```

index.js in back

```
const server = require('http').createServer(app)
const { Server } = require('socket.io')

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: { origin: 'https://myurl.com' }
});
const port = process.env.PORT || 3030;

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

I made the pertinent changes in nginx to adapt it to secured urls and stuff

Comment: What is the nginx proxy config?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29232687/1318694